# TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

so I wrote the following code:

```
    "use strict";

import React from 'react';
import { TableHeader, TableBody, TableRow, TableColumn, Button } from 'react- 
md';
import { DataTable } from 'react-md';

import { VoteListRow } from './VoteListRow';
import Page from './Page'


export const VoteList = ({data}) => (
    <Page>
        <DataTable plain>
            <TableHeader>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableColumn>Question</TableColumn>
                    <TableColumn>Number of Items</TableColumn>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
                {data.map((poll) => <VoteListRow poll={poll}/>)}
            </TableBody>
        </DataTable>
    </Page>
);
```

and i currently receive the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined at VoteList.js: 20. I see that there is probably an error with the imports, but I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Just offhand it looks like the `poll` variable that you're accessing from `data` is undefined (ie. no data being sent to the `<VoteListRow>` component). Are you sure that your `data` variable is populated with something that also has access to a `displayName` property?

Comment: Slightly off-topic (because that's what comments are for, right?) ... do people like to pass data into a component that "only" does layout, like this, and then pass bits of that data down to children? I've only worked with flux or redux (never with react only) so my first thought is to make the `<TableBody>[<VoteListRow/>]</TableBody>` section into its own component, wrapped in Redux.connect(). Does that make sense?